# how to create an arrow without using image in HTML?

Tags: html

how to create an arrow without using image in HTML? I have a jquery plugin or Testimonials where they have created an arrow without using image by using following style :

```
#testimonials .item div.text:after {
    content: " ";
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 50%;
}
```

I cant figure out this styles.

Comment: Use an arrow character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Comment: I had no idea [Google](http://hedgerwow.appspot.com/demo/arrows) [was](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/) [broken](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Answer (score 3):

`&larr;` will create a ← character

`&rarr;` will create a → character.

etc..

Have a look at [HTML characters](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/ASCII-HTML-Characters/).

It really depends on what kind of arrow you want to create.

Answer (score 1):

Either use web fonts like [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) else as @Oded said, you can use an arrow character with CSS `content` property, in case of list or use HTML entities like `&larr;` or `&rarr;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/USmPy/)

```
ul li:before {
     content: '→ ';
}
```